# why torch.autograd could not compute the full Jacobian directly while it is mathematically achiveable

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I am reading the pytorch tutorial on [this page](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html).

It says:

> Now in this case y is no longer a scalar. torch.autograd could not compute the full Jacobian directly, but if we just want the vector-Jacobian product, simply pass the vector to backward as argument"

Which I dont understand, because we actually can do the full Jacobian calculation mathematically. Why does it say that?

And where is this `v` coming from? Why do I want to pass this argument to my `backward()`.

```
v = torch.tensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001], dtype=torch.float)
y.backward(v)
```

It is quite confusing.